# How to rewrite rules with nginx regular expressions

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

using nginx( version >1 ) rewrite
I would like to rewrite

www.domain.com/local/airports/jfk-2/
as
www.domain.com/local/airports/jfk/

There are too many locations like above.

I tried below without luck
rewrite ^/local/airports/(.*)/ /local/airports/$1-2/ permanent;

What is the best way to get this work?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want a redirect? or just a rewrite ?

Comment: I want to redirect the page

Comment: is there any thing after like `jfk-2/something`, or does it end there ?

Comment: It ends there  with jfk-2

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a bit too specific redirect but as far as I understand is you don't need any thing more than this

```
location /local/airports/(.*)-2 {
    return 301 http://example.com/local/airports/$1;
}
```